# PySpark: SQLContext temp table is not returning any table

Tags: pyspark

I am quite new to PySpark. Therefore this question may appear as quite elementary to others. 
I am trying to export a data frame created via `createOrReplaceTempView()` to Hive. The steps are as follows

```
sqlcntx = SQLContext(sc)
df = sqlcntx.read.format("jdbc").options(url="sqlserver://.....details of MS Sql server",dbtable = "table_name").load()
df_cv_temp = df.createOrReplaceTempView("df")
```

When I use `df_cv_temp.show(5)` it is giving an error as follows

```
NoneType Object has no attribute 'show'
```

Interestingly when I try to see `df.show(5)` I am getting proper output. 
Naturally when I see the above error I am not able to proceed further.

Now I have two questions.

1. How to fix the above issue?
2. Assuming the 1st issue is taken care of, what is the best way to export `df_cv_temp` to HIVE tables?

P.S. I am using PySaprk 2.0

**Update: Incorporating Jim's Answer**

Post answer received from Jim, I have updated the code. Please see below the revised code.

```
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext,SQLContext
sql_cntx = SQLContext(sc)
df = sqlcntx.read.format("jdbc").options(url="sqlserver://.....details of MS Sql server",dbtable = "table_name").load()
df_curr_volt.createOrReplaceTempView("df_cv_temp")
df_cv_filt = sql_cntx.sql("select * from df_cv_temp where DeviceTimeStamp between date_add(current_date(),-1) and current_date()") # Retrieving just a day's record
hc = HiveContext(sc)
```

Now the problem begins. Please refer to my question 2.

```
df_cv_tbl = hc.sql("create table if not exits df_cv_raw as select * from df_cv_filt")
df_cv_tbl.write.format("orc").saveAsTable("df_cv_raw")
```

The above two lines is producing the error as shown below.

`pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u'Table or view not found: df_cv_filt; line 1 pos 14'`

So what is the right way of approaching this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
df_cv_temp = df.createOrReplaceTempView("df")
```

you have to use,

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("table1")
```

This is because, `df.createOrReplaceTempView(<name_of_the_view>)` creates (or replaces if that view name already exists) a lazily evaluated "view" that you can then use like a hive table in Spark SQL. The expression does not produce any output as such, hence it is a **NoneType** object.

Further, the temp view can be queried as below:

```
spark.sql("SELECT field1 AS f1, field2 as f2 from table1").show()
```

Incase, you are sure to have memory space, then you can **persist it to be a hive table directly** like below. This will create a managed Hive table physically; upon which you can query it even in your Hive CLI.

```
df.write.saveAsTable("table1")
```

Comment: So when you say 'a lazily evaluated "view" that you can then use like a hive table in Spark SQL' does it mean I can't use the following query for creating another table name 'tbl'? `hc = HiveContext(hc) ; tbl = hc.sql('CREATE TABLE df_final AS SELECT * FROM table1")`

Comment: Yes, you can use as you have mentioned above. Then, you can print as tbl.show(). That will work. Upvote if it worked.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not working. I have edited the question post your recommendation.

Comment: 'tbl' as per your case is now a dataframe. The result set of the sql will be stored to tbl as dataframe. Whats the error you get now?

Comment: I edited the answer, to create a actual Hive table from the df. Check if that works.